# Unload dll as Process Hacker does

Tags: c, winapi, dll, module, process

I want to unload a program's DLL as Process Hacker does.

I'm getting list of modules with `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPALL, dwProcId)` which allows me a `MODULEENTRY32` containing information of the DLL I want to unload.

But `FreeLibrary()` or `FreeLibraryAndExitThread()` don't do anything as the dll is in use by the program. It's why I don't get how Process Hacker does it while it's in use.

So here's my question: How does Process Hacker unload dll that are used by another program? I've tried to look into the source code but can't find anything.

Now I know that it can cause the program to crash, but it isn't a problem.

Comment: This is an open source software. You want us to read the source for you? Wouldn't it be better for you to read the source to find out how it is done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you try unload dll in self process ? if yes - just call `FreeLibrary`. if in another process - you need call `CreateRemoteThread` with entry point to `FreeLibrary` and `hmod` as param. of course if you run in the same terminal session with target process (connected to the same *csrss*), otherwise you need use more low level routine for create thread (`RtlCreateUserThread`) and shell code which call `FreeLibrary`  and exit, because entry point for `RtlCreateUserThread` must direct call `RtlExitUserThread` or `ExitThread`. (entry point for `CreateRemoteThread` can simply return - `ExitThread` will be auto called after this)

anyway library can be pinned and can not be unloaded by `FreeLibrary` - look for example [`GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_PIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683200(v=vs.85).aspx). also all libraries which is statically load by exe import always pinned - can not be unloaded by `FreeLibrary`.

also exist option - direct call [`ZwUnmapViewOfSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwunmapviewofsection) with target process handle and *BaseAddress* of dll - dll is mapped via [`ZwMapViewOfSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwmapviewofsection) and can be always unmapped via [`ZwUnmapViewOfSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwunmapviewofsection) (even if "pinned" ). of course loader structures for dll will be not free in this case, but dll itself will be unmapped from process address space.

however both ways is incorrect - what will be if somebody call this dll after this ?

> I know that it can cause the program to crash but it isn't a problem.

in this case - simply terminate program - call `TerminateProcess` and all. this is more simply and efficient compare try unload concrete dll with the same final effect